# Remove a fragment of a specific index from a view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Im trying to remove a fragment from a specific index. But that is really happening is the viewpager and pagerAdapter are just hiding the last fragment.

This is the code:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

ArrayList<String> data_fragment;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    data_fragment = new ArrayList<>();
    data_fragment.add(0, "Página 0");
}

public void addNewFragmentData(String data) {
    // int last_position = data_fragment.size();
    data_fragment.add(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void removeFragmentData(int index) {
    // destroyItem(container, position, object);
    data_fragment.remove(index);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

    return POSITION_NONE;
}

// @Override
// public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
// {
// data_fragment.remove(position);
// super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
// }

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Log.i("paginas", "getItem");
    return LienzoFragment.newInstance(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data_fragment.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return data_fragment.get(position);
    }
}
```

As you see, I'm trying to avoid retain any fragment object. My approach is just keep the title and then each fragment manage its own save/restore state by itself.

```
int tab_selected = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
mSectionsPagerAdapter.removeFragmentData(tab_selected);
//mSectionsPagerAdapter.destroyItem(mViewPager, tab_selected, mViewPager.getChildAt(tab_selected));
mViewPager.removeViewAt(tab_selected);
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab_selected-1, true);
```

Comment: maybe another approach?